# Compile Error on Macro to Split and Save Worksheets

Tags: vba, split, macros, save, worksheet

I'm having a problem getting my code to compile - I'm not sure why.

The code itself is based off of this:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/628-excel-split-workbook.html

It saves each individual worksheet as a excel file, with the worksheet name as the filename - this works fine.

I wanted to change the filename it saves as. Right now it only saves the name as the worksheetname.xls, however I want the name to be workbookname_worksheetname.xls. This is where I'm having problems. I think I tried something involving activeworkbook.name, but that gave me the whole file name, so when saving I got a crazy name like workbookname.xlsx_worksheetname.xls. I started looking into how I could get only the filename and it led me to these posts which I've tried to incorporate as well:

[How do I use FileSystemObject in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba/3236348#3236348)
[File name without extension name VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923926/file-name-without-extension-name-vba)

However, I'm getting a compile error: syntax error on the following line:

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xFilename & "_" & xWs.Name,
    FileFormat:=39
```

Can someone help review and cleanup the code if necessary? Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
Sub Splitbook()
'https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1174-excel-split-data-into-multiple-worksheets-based-on-column.html
'https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/628-excel-split-workbook.html
Dim xPath As String
Dim xFilename As String
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba/3236348#3236348
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923926/file-name-without-extension-name-vba
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
xFilename = fso.GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xFilename & "_" & xWs.Name,
    FileFormat:=39
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need the line extension.  If you want to split a line of code over two lines you need a `_` so it should look like
    `Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xFilename & "_" & xWs.Name, _`

or put the whole thing on one line

See [How to extend a formula in VBA past 1 line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979916/how-to-extend-a-formula-in-vba-past-1-line-of-code)

Comment: Ah. It was a much simpler issue than I thought.  Thank you for your help!